# Test if an object conforms to an interface in TypeScript

Tags: testing, typescript

If I have a plain-old JavaScript object and a TypeScript interface, how can I write a test that asserts object conforming to my interface?

```
interface Person {
  name: string
  age?: number
}

describe('Person interface check', () => {
  it ('should conform to "Person" interface', () => {
     let obj1 = {name: "Mohsen"};
     let obj2 = {name: "Hommer", age: 40};

     expect(obj1) // ????
  });
});
```

**EDIT**: I don't want to do deep assertion, eg `expect(obj1.name).to.be.a.string`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Interface type check with Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14425568/interface-type-check-with-typescript)

Comment: You can also consider using [Runtypes](https://github.com/pelotom/runtypes).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> asserts object conforming to my interface

You have to do it manually:

```
expect(typeof object.name).to.eql("string");
// so on
```

## Update : Writing code to do the deep assertion for you

Since the type information *TypeScript* sees is *removed* in the generated JS you don't have access to the type information *in js*. However you can write code to take the TS view of the code (using the typescript language service) and generate the JS code that does these deep assertions for you.

Comment: sadly its not easy yet

Answer (score 4):

I just had the same problem and my solution was to build a [json schema](https://json-schema.org) of my interface.
You can use an [automated tool](https://github.com/YousefED/typescript-json-schema) to built it for you by passing your custom interface like this:

```sh
typescript-json-schema "./myfile.ts" MyCustomType --strictNullChecks --noExtraProps --required --out=output.json
```

Then, you can use the extension [jest-json-schema](https://github.com/americanexpress/jest-json-schema) to check if your object matches your generated schema like this:

```js
const mySchema = require('path/to/output.json')
expect(myStrangeObject).toMatchSchema(mySchema)
```

This worked like a charm for me.

(I'd recommend getting familiar with json schema keywords because those flags "--strictNullChecks --noExtraProps --required" makes a big difference when generating the schema depending on your interface definition)

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of different packages that would allow you to test this at "typecheck" time.

Here's an example using one that I wrote: https://tsplay.dev/oN94ow