# How to use 'unknown' without instanceof in a meaningful way?

Tags: typescript

Since *TypeScript 3.0* the new top type **unknown** is available as a type-safe counterpart of **any**.

I really love this type, as it makes the code even more robust.

My main problem with this is, that *TypeScript* (obviously) does not provide an `instanceof`-feature at runtime for interfaces. If it would (be possible), this code would work quite well:

```
class Test {

  doSomething(value: unknown) {
    if(value instanceof MySuperInterface) {
      return value.superFunction();
    }

    return false;
  }

}
```

**My question**

How do I use this type in a meaningful way, without the need of checking each property of my interface?

Comment: In conjunction with discriminated unions maybe?

Comment: Pick a couple of properties that are significant and use custom type guard to narrow `unknown` to your specific interface type ?

Answer (score 0):

Javascipt does not check for interface type at runtime.

[instanceof check on interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31748277/typescript-instanceof-check-on-interface)

But, you can use unknown type with classes as shown below:

```
interface MySuperInterface {
    superfunction(): string;
}

class MySuperImplementation implements MySuperInterface {
    superfunction(): string {
        return "Hello from super function";
    }
}

class Greeter {
    greeting: string;

    constructor(message: string) {
        this.greeting = message;
    }

    greet() {
        return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
    }

    testSuperFunction(value: unknown) {
        if (value instanceof MySuperImplementation) {
            return value.superfunction();
        }
        else {
            return "Error";
        }
    }
}

let greeter = new Greeter("world");

const sfunc = new MySuperImplementation();

console.log(greeter.testSuperFunction(sfunc));
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)