# How to resolve typescript union types of interfaces with type guards

Tags: typescript

Angular's `$http.defaults.transformRequest` is defined as:

```
transformRequest?: IHttpRequestTransformer |IHttpRequestTransformer[];
```

Now I want to append an own transformer, so I need to check if this is already an array. I thought a simple typeguard with

```
function x(): angular.IHttpRequestTransformer[] { 
    if($http.defaults.transformRequest instanceof Array){
       return $http.defaults.transformRequest;
    }
}
```

would work, however, inside the if clause idea still thinks it is a union type. I also tried `instanceof` and `$http.defaults.transformRequest.length === undefined`, nothing worked.

Can anyone hint me in the right direction how I can tell IDEA that I've already ensured that `$http.defaults.transformRequest` is an array?

Thank!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type guards don't work on properties in TypeScript < 2.0. They only work on variables and parameters.

You will need to either put it in a variable and type guard that...

```
let transformRequest = $http.defaults.transformRequest;
if (transformRequest instanceof Array) {
    return transformRequest;
}
```

...**or** just use a type assertion:

```
if ($http.defaults.transformRequest instanceof Array) {
    return $http.defaults.transformRequest as IHttpRequestTransformer[];
}
```

Comment: transformRequest instanceof InterfaceType throws 'InterfaceType' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here. [2693]

Comment: @Iohiarahul it's not possible to use interfaces at runtime in TypeScript. Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14425568/interface-type-check-with-typescript).