# TypeScript - Check if Class implements an Interface

Tags: typescript

I'm using an interface in TypeScript to define a function that is only available on some of the classes that extend the base class. This is a simplified version of the code I have so far:

```
class Animal {
}

interface IWalkingAnimal {
    walk(): void;
}

class Dog extends Animal implements IWalkingAnimal {
}

class Cat extends Animal implements IWalkingAnimal {
}

class Snake extends Animal {
}

private moveAnimal(animal: Animal) {
    if (animal instanceof Cat || animal instanceof Dog) {
        animal.walk();
    }
}
```

Now, the trouble is I'll be adding more 'walking' animals so the moveAnimal functional will grow too large to be manageable. What I would like to do is something like this:

```
private moveAnimal(animal: Animal) {
    if (animal implements IWalkingAnimal ) {
        animal.walk();
    }
}
```

However the 'implements' check does not work, and I cannot find an equivalent to 'instanceof' when using interfaces. In Java it seems that the use of 'instanceof' would work here, but TypeScript will not allow this.

Does such a thing exist in TypeScript, or is there a better approach here? I am using the TypeScript 1.8.9.

Comment: why don't you have `IWalkingAnimal` being a subclass of Animal instead an interface? That way you won't have the problem and it makes sense

Comment: @iberbeu That would work for this simplified example, for flexibility I would like IWalkingAnimal to be an interface so it is not strictly tied to Animal. Thilo's answer below should do the trick.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Interface type check with Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14425568/interface-type-check-with-typescript)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Unlike classes, interfaces exist only at compile-time, they are not included into the resulting JavaScript, so you cannot do an `instanceof` check.

You could make `IWalkingAnimal` a subclass of Animal (and use `instanceof`), or you could check if the object in question has a `walk` method:

```
if (animal['walk']) {}
```

You can wrap this in a [user defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) (so that the compiler can narrow the type when used in an `if` statement, just like with `instanceof`).

```
/**
* User Defined Type Guard!
*/
function canWalk(arg: Animal): arg is IWalkingAnimal {
   return (arg as IWalkingAnimal).walk !== undefined;
}


private moveAnimal(animal: Animal) {
    if (canWalk(animal)) {
        animal.walk();  // compiler knows it can walk now
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest to do `(arg as IWalkingAnimal).walk` so that if you decide to rename the walk method to something else then the code in the type guard will change as well.

Comment: Is this type check bettter then the `instanceof` subclass option?—OO design wise?