# Parse array of JSON objects to array of TypeScript objects

Tags: angular

I have an endpoint that returns this Json:

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Kayak",
      "category": "Watersports",
      "description": "A boat for one person",
      "price": 27500,
      "currencyCode": "EUR"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Lifejacket",
      "category": "Watersports",
      "description": "Protective and fashionable",
      "price": 48095,
      "currencyCode": "EUR"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Soccer Ball",
      "category": "Soccer",
      "description": "FIFA-approved size and weight",
      "price": 1950,
      "currencyCode": "EUR"
    }
]
}
```

I have a class called `Product` in Angular:

```
import { Money, Currencies } from 'ts-money';

export class Product {
private money: Money;
public Amount = this.money.amount;

public constructor(
    public Id: number,
    public Name: string,
    public Category: string,
    public Price: number,
    public Description: string,
    public CurrencyCode: string) {
        this.money = new Money(Price, CurrencyCode);
    }

public GetPrice(): Money {
    return this.money;
}
}
```

I made this code in Angular:

```
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private datasource: ProductDataSource) {
  }

  private products: Product[];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.datasource.GetProducts()
    .subscribe((data) => {
        this.products = data;
    });
  }
 }
}
```

This code successfully returns an array of JSON objects that have the same properties as `Product`. Now, when I subscribe to this observable:

```
this.datasource.GetProducts()
.subscribe((data) => {
    // this.products is a class property of type Product[]
    this.products = data; // How do I make this work?
});
```

I can not figure out how to make the transition from JSON object to Angular class. My HTML page does not recognize `this.products` as an array of `Product` objects. What do I do?

Comment: How is declared / initialized `this.products` in your component and how are you using it in your template? Can you add this to your question please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Product` properties names and json properties names doesn't match.
You can do it like this:

```
this.datasource.GetProducts()
  .subscribe((data) => {
    // this.products is a class property of type Product[]
    this.products = (data || []).map(item => new Product(item.id, item.name, item.category, item.price, item.description, item.currencyCode))
  });
```

Comment: It's more easy to change product from class to interface and do the correct JSON mapping inside the interface, this map add complexity for nothing

Comment: totally agree, but mapping still an option too

Comment: you may also do `new Product(item)` and move the complexity inside the constructor...

Comment: I didn't say it wasn't an option, I think there is better way to do so :)

Comment: @Random, if properties names in `Product` and json doesn't match (as we have in a question. Product properties names are Capitalized) - this will not work.

Comment: @qiAlex i'm talking about moving the complexity, so the constructor will do `this.Id = item.id`, etc...

Comment: @Random yeah, this is also an option

Comment: Thanks, with some minor changes this solution worked best for me!

Answer (score 4):

I think it's because of your mapping in your product class and also the type of your class, try to change class Product to interface Product

like this

```
    export interface Product{

    public id: number;
    public name: string;
    public category: string;
    public price: number;
    public description: string;
    public currencyCode: string; 

 }
```

you can go take a look at [Angular : Class and Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54356711/angular-class-and-interface/54356916) for the differences between class and interface

EDIT : (as you can see in my code, I also changed the variable name to match with your JSON response)

Answer (score 2):

Another approach could be to make **JSON** data, compatible with your **Product** class. You could use the **map** rxjs operator to transform your JSON data into **Product**. Modify the get products code, like this

```js
    const source$ = of(result).pipe(pluck('result'),map(item=> item.map(x=>{
      let product = new Product(x.id,x.name, x.category, x.price, x.description, x.currencyCode);
      return product;
    })));
```

Here is a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vhy6ub) link.

Comment: rxjs is a good approach, but using it with a `of` is odd. You may do the same thing inside `datasource.GetProducts()` method (which is not detailed in the question), directly on the http call

Comment: Yes. Actually I just wrote this as an example only to reproduce the scenario in my stackblitz code.

Answer (score 0):

create product interface with variables and use that interface to create array

```
    export interface Product{
      public Id: number,
      public Name: string,
      public Category: string,
      public Price: number,
      public Description: string,
      public CurrencyCode: string
    }

     products:Product[];
```

Comment: @Random it depend on how your project is set up, from the JSON you can see it's camelCase and not PascalCase

Comment: I'm talking about interface name, not attributes. Indeed attributes name depends on what the server responds, but should be camelCase (where in the question, attributes are PascalCase which is odd)

Answer (score 0):

Change class to interface and change the case of also.

```
export interface Product{

public id: number;
public name: string;
public category: string;
public price: number;
public description: string;
public currencyCode: string; }
```

Comment: "just", but also change "class" to "interface"... ^^