# Where do you typically put your typescript class definitions in angular?

Tags: angular

Say that I'm building an app that is a car app, and I want to define what a car looks like using a typescript class. Where should I put that file in relation to my car component? Should I have a whole new folder that houses all of my class files? Should the class file be in with my component? Is there a standard? I would think having them in a folder outside of the component would make most sense so that they are more reusable. Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's up to you. Whatever puts your OCD at ease.

However, here's what I would do:

- Create an `interface` or `class` that represents a Car
- If the `Car` model is only used within the Car Component, create a folder called `models` within your Car Component. However, if the `Car` model is used in many different places, I would put in **/shared/models/car.ts**. This is helpful when you start to get a bunch of classes and you can have a pattern of "local classes" and "shared classes"

Example of what your `Car` might look like:

```
export interface Car {
  make: string;
  model: string;
  year: number;
  color: string;
}
```

Read through this SOF thread if you have any confusion on `class` vs `interface`

[Angular : Class and Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54356711/angular-class-and-interface/54356916#54356916)

Comment: Haha, thanks, I was just diagnosed with OCD the other day actually so this is beyond funny.