# Typescript objects deserialization using classes vs interfaces

Tags: typescript

I'm new to ts and I'm trying to deserialize a json to a statically typed object

like this

```
class Bar {
    x:number;
    y?:string; 
 }
  
interface IBar{
    x:number;
    y?:string; 
}

var baz:IBar = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

i want to know in this case what the difference between using

```
var baz:IBar = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

and

```
var baz:Bar = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

i have read [Interfaces vs Types in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37233735/interfaces-vs-types-in-typescript)
but it did not help

Comment: Take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55505227/10691359, it will help you choose between those two choices.

Comment: Saying it is "that class" may work in some ways, but it won't be `instanceof` nor would it have any functions on the class. Either use the interface or create a parse function for your class, or object assign the data into an instance.