# When to use classes vs. interfaces in a TypeScript library?

Tags: typescript

I have seen related questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55505227/169992), but they all assume the difference between classes and interfaces are that classes can be *instantiated* while interfaces cannot. However, take for example [@types/google.maps](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/c4e1b1616f8264ba63bf164407752e6de5db81da/types/google.maps/index.d.ts). For example:

```
declare namespace google.maps {
  class Map extends google.maps.MVCObject {
    constructor(mapDiv: HTMLElement, opts?: google.maps.MapOptions);
    controls: google.maps.MVCArray<any>[];
    data: google.maps.Data;
    fitBounds(
        bounds: google.maps.LatLngBounds|google.maps.LatLngBoundsLiteral,
        padding?: number|google.maps.Padding): void;
    // ...
  }
}
declare namespace google.maps {
  interface MapType {
    alt: string|null;
    getTile(
        tileCoord: google.maps.Point|null, zoom: number,
        ownerDocument: Document|null): Element|null;
    maxZoom: number;
    minZoom: number;
    name: string|null;
    projection: google.maps.Projection|null;
    radius: number;
    releaseTile(tile: Element|null): void;
    tileSize: google.maps.Size|null;
  }
}
declare namespace google.maps {
  interface MapTypeControlOptions {
    mapTypeIds?: (string)[]|null;
    position?: google.maps.ControlPosition|null;
    style?: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle|null;
  }
}
declare namespace google.maps {
  class MapTypeRegistry extends google.maps.MVCObject {
    set(id: string, mapType: any): void;
  }
}
declare namespace google.maps {
  interface MapsEventListener {
    remove(): void;
  }
}
declare namespace google.maps {
  interface WebglCameraParams extends google.maps.CameraParams {
    lat: number;
    lng: number;
  }
}
```

Both interfaces and classes:

- Extend other objects.
- Have properties.
- Have methods/functions.
- Cannot be directly instantiated from these definitions.

Somewhere in the google maps code there is actually a **class** for both the `class`es defined here, and the `interface`s defined here. It appears that the class definitions are for what a user can instantiate, vs. what the library can internally instantiate (interfaces).

So then, what are the deeper differences between interfaces and classes in these contexts? I get like what the other answer is saying, that classes *usually* are constructable, but these classes clearly are not directly instantiable. They represent other classes. But the interfaces represent other classes too. So I am confused.

Comment: *"Both interfaces and classes: ... Cannot be directly instantiated from these definitions."* What interfaces and classes are you referring to there? You can instantiate `Map` from those definitions (and I have, many times), and I'd expect to be able to instantiate `MapTypeRegistry` (though I can't say that I have). (Obviously, you have to have the runtime objects to back up the type definitions.)

Comment: I mean it's not a _literal_ `class X { }` in JS, it's defined within typescript, as can be seen with the methods not being filled out. The literal class is defined within the google maps library.

Comment: Note that you're looking at a `.d.ts`file (evidenced by the `@types` part. It'll never contain any real code, just the type definitions for a normal JS file. In a real typescript project you'll find that classes have its full definition, while interfaces are still definitions-only.

Comment: I get that. Which is why I'm asking why they defined them as classes and not interfaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*(From [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71512288/when-to-use-classes-vs-interfaces-in-a-typescript-library/71513155#comment126394905_71512288))*:

> I'm asking why they defined them as classes and not interfaces.

There's overlap between `type`, `interface`, and `class` (you clearly know that, but I have to start somewhere :-) ), but `class` does *three* things rather than just the one thing that `interface` or `type` would do. Let's look at a simpler example:

```
declare namespace example1 {
    class Example1 {
        a: string;
        constructor(a: string);
        static method(): void;
    }
}
```

That:

- Defines the type `Example1` which describes instances.
- Defines that there is a runtime binding, `Example1`, that refers to the constructor function for those instances. (It doesn't *create* the binding, it just says there is one.)
- (Implicitly) Defines a type (`typeof Example1`) that is the type of the constructor function.

If you wanted to write the same thing without `class`, you'd have to write each of those three things yourself, such as `example2` here:

```
declare namespace example2 {
    // Define the type for instances
    interface Example2 {
        a: string;
    }
    // Define that there is a binding for the constructor function
    let Example2: {                 //
        new (a: string): Example2;  // Define the type for the constructor function
        method(): void;             //
    };                              //
}
```

You might even go further and declare a named type for the constructor function:

```
declare namespace example3 {
    // Define the type for instances
    interface Example3 {
        a: string;
    }
    // Define the type for the constructor function
    interface Example3Constructor {
        new (a: string): Example3;
        method(): void;
    }
    // Define that there is a binding for the constructor function
    let Example3: Example3Constructor;
}
```

(That's what `lib.es5.d.ts` does for, say, `Array`, except it uses `var` instead of `let`.)

As always when there's more than one way to do something, some folks will do it one way, others will do it another, but there's some argument for using `class` when it describes all of the parts you're trying to describe at once.