# how can I check if an object complies to an interface

Tags: typescript

Suppose I have an interface `MyInterface`

Is there a native way in typescript to check if an object complies to `MyInterface` ?

Like `instanceof` but against an interface instead of a class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14425568/interface-type-check-with-typescript

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no way, because I tried it several times with `instanceof`. It works for classes although.

So you have to check for the props of the object e.g.

```
if((object as SomeInterface).interfaceMethod)){
  // it's SomeInterface
} else {
  // it's not
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no native way, but [ts-interface-checker](https://github.com/gristlabs/ts-interface-checker) module can be used for runtime tests and validations.

It needs a runtime description of the interface, which can be built from the TypeScript interfaces in one step using the companion [ts-interface-builder](https://github.com/gristlabs/ts-interface-builder) module.

Comment: I run `npm bin ts-interface-builder Widget_PieChartModel.ts` and nothing happening. i run the command from the folder where the file is ts located. Any clue @ds. Thanks for posting.

Comment: `npm bin` (No other args) gives the location of the executable files. Try it again with backticks as in README or run `node_modules/.bin/ts-interface-builder`. The output will be a new file next to the origiinal.

Comment: I opened bin folder in terminal and executed `ts-interface-builder E:....\PieChart\Widget_PieChartModel.ts` . @DS thank you

Comment: And do you see now a new file `E:....\PieChart\Widget_PieChartModel-ti.ts`? If yes, it can be used with `ts-interface-checker` module for runtime validations. If not, file a bug report at https://github.com/gristlabs/ts-interface-builder/issues with as much detail as possible.

Comment: I ti file is generated. I am using in condition checking. I few issue there. Let me try. thanks again @DS