# Getting all the property types of an Interface in Typescript

Tags: typescript

The Dream:

```
 interface foo {
    buzz: string;
    das: number;
    bar: string[];
 }

 function findAllProperties(randomObject: any): string[] {
    // someone more versed in TS and smarter than me?
 }
```

This would be used for the first step in an 'assert all' function for properties on a given type, so when I pass a prop into a component I could assert all for not being null | undefined. I can't find any way to do this, and the others are in the belief its impossible.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Please elaborate.

Comment: Those types do not exist at runtime, so you cannot call a function and check if buzz is a string. Type checking only exists at compile time and works automatically, so that you don't NEED an assert function at runtime.

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/14426274/251311 ?

Comment: @Kokodoko yea I've voiced that typescript compile checks, he then found the one way to pass a null into a prop without TS complaining by using a function(){}:any    even though my tslint won't even allow any.

just looking for a way to clean up my code without 5 lines of assertions in every component. You gave me a good laugh and I passed it on to bossman haha, thank you.

Comment: @Wikkle_A why do you use `any` as a type instead of `foo` ? Also, considering what you said about `null` : have you enabled `strictNullChecks` mode in your `tsconfig` ?

Comment: @Jules Randolph because I'd like to write a function that can take any interface and then spit back a string[] representing its properties, not just my 'foo' interface. And yes, I have strictNullChecks so 'any' doesn't even work within the project :/

Comment: @Wikkle_A perhaps you looking for https://github.com/kimamula/ts-transformer-keys

Comment: I literally said 'omg' outloud. That looks amazing, I'll be taking a look

Comment: @Wikkle_A typescript custom transformers is a branding new, really promising feature ! Enjoy :-)

Comment: @Wikkle_A however I can't figure out how you might extract the interface from the object at runtime... I'm not sure I understand the use-case :/