# Safely Access Property on Optional Flow Type

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I want to safely access a property on a Union Type (all options are interfaces) set by external library(mobx).

```
 Cannot call observe because:
 Either property added is missing in IArrayChange [1] but exists in IArraySplice [2] in the first argument.
 Or property added is missing in IObjectChange [3] but exists in IArraySplice [2] in the first argument.

 142│     observe(thisContainer.items, (change: IArraySplice<any>) => {
 143│        change.added.forEach((item: Item) => this.observeChanges(item));
 145│     });
 146│   }
 147│

 node_modules/mobx/lib/mobx.js.flow
  356│     listener: (change: IArrayChange<T> | IArraySplice<T>) => void,

  372│     listener: (change: IObjectChange) => void,
```

I have tried:

- using conditionals to check whether `.added` exists before running change.added.iterator. `if (change.added){` && `if ('added' in change) {`
- using a condition to check that the universally available property `type` is set to `splice`. This should ensure that the property added is also available. `change.type === 'splice' && change.added...`.

The docs suggest is typical to write conditions for type checks
https://flow.org/en/docs/types/unions/
But I am unsure of the best way to do this w/ an external library's interfaces. Authoring functions such as [Interface type check with Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14425568/interface-type-check-with-typescript) feels heavier than I'd like for meeting the rules pre-commit type checker.

How should this be done?

Answer (score 0):

**Working solution:**

```
observe(thisContainer.items, (change: IArraySplice<any> | IArraySplice<T>) => {
    if (change.type === 'splice') {
        change.added.forEach((item: Item) => this.observeChanges(item));
    }
});
```

**Explanation:**

Though the error message focuses on the existence of the property, the error is triggered b/c the passed argument is not necessarily as anticipated.

Since mobx `IObservableArray` changes can generate either `IArraySplice<T>` or `IArraySplice<T>`, the Flow types need to account for either.

Once that is handled, properties available on both expected are available for refinement.

**For reference, the implementation the mobx types:**

```
export interface IArrayChange<T> {
    type: "update",
    object: IObservableArray<T>,
    index: number,
    newValue: T,
    oldValue: T
}

export interface IArraySplice<T> {
    type: "splice",
    object: IObservableArray<T>,
    index: number,
    added: T[],
    addedCount: number,
    removed: T[],
    removedCount: number
}
```