# Check object interface via Typescript

Tags: typescript

Is there a best way to check an object against a typescript infterface?

I am working between two schemas, where one extends the other. I need to convert the extension back to base, and am doing so by deleting props from the extension to shape it to the original base class. An example:

```
interface Base {
  prop1: string
  prop2?: string
  prop3?: string
}

interface Extended extends Base {
  prop4: string
  prop5: string
}
```

So in order to get `Extended` back to `Base`, I need to `delete` props `prop4` and `prop5`

This is of course easy enough to do, but, I need to ensure that the final result conforms to the `Base` class, since [deleting props does not tell the compiler anything](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13783), and the extension will pass the `Base` type check.

I have looked at using a type guard, and [other alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14425568/interface-type-check-with-typescript), however, I have not found a way to do this which accommodates for the optional properties found in `Base`, or a seemingly efficient way to do it.

Here is a basic plan for the type guard as well as handling optional props:

```
function isBase(arg: any): arg is Base {
  return arg
    && arg.prop1
    && (arg.prop2 || true)
    && (arg.prop3 || true)
}
```

Besides being a lot of work for a lot of props, it's brittle. Soon as `Base` changes, this technique no longer works as intended. I feel like there is (should be) some Typescript way via utility types that could check the props against the `Base` interface, so it will always work as intended.

***Update***

I found [this](https://dev.to/krumpet/generic-type-guard-in-typescript-258l). Looks very close but could not get it working with interfaces.

Comment: Utility types wouldn't work since interface are design-time types and not run-time types, therefore you'd need to have type-guard code compiled in the first place, which will then run. Type guards are the only solution AFAIK.

Comment: "I need to convert the extension back to base" Why? If the type extends a base then that type can be treated as a base, you don't need to remove properties...

Comment: The extension is used for client side purposes, and the base is what is stored in the db. So while it can be treated as the base, I do not want to store the additional data the extension holds (in the db), and want to check that is the case before sending it across the wire.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to keep `Base` as a standalone property, using *composition* instead of *inheritance* might be a better approach, for instance:

```
interface Base {
  prop1: string
  prop2?: string
  prop3?: string
}

interface Extended {
  data: Base
  prop4: string
  prop5: string
}
```

Do whatever is needed with `Extended` but only send `data` to database.

Comment: This looks like a good technique. Although that means all uses of `Extended` class would need to be updated to have the `data` prop that consists of `Base`.