# Check type of interface - Model only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here

Tags: typescript

I have a Typescript interface:

```
export interface BookModel {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  publishedAt: Date;
}
```

And I am using as:

```
let book: BookModel = { id: 1, title: "Title", publishedAt: new Date(2018, 10, 12); }

let valid = this.validate(Requirement.IsNew, book);
```

Where validate method is:

```
validate(requirement: Requirement, resource: any) : boolean {
  if (resource instanceof BookModel) {

  }
  if (resource instanceof PostModel) {

  }
  return false;
}
```

I get an error when trying to check if resource type is `BookModel` or `PostModel` or ...:

```
'BookModel' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
```

I need to check the type as the validation process depends on type.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Interface type check with Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14425568/interface-type-check-with-typescript)

Comment: As I see, your code supposed to make a runtime validation, while TS interface does not exist on that stage, therefore TS gives you an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeScript type annotation don't exists in the runtime, also `instanceof` operator works only with prototypes, it means that you need to have custom prototype in the object to work with this operator (use function constructor or ES6 Class).

`BookModel` is plain object, there is no additional prototype to check (outside object prototype). That is why you cannot use instanceof, and as said before `BookModel` as a type cannot be used as a runtime value.

What we can use instead is type representation - the data structure. To differentiate `BookModel` from `PostModel` we need to find what props are different, find the [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union). If you don't have any special property which differs between 
`BookModel` and `PostModel`, such can be created. Below I have used `_type`:

```
export interface BookModel {
  _type: 'Book', // special meta information as discriminant
  id: number;
  title: string;
  publishedAt: Date;
}

export interface PostModel {
  _type: 'Post',// special meta information as discriminant
  id: number;
  title: string;
  publishedAt: Date;
}

// below I removed first argument for readability
// check also that resource is now specified as a union type
function validate(resource: BookModel | PostModel) : boolean {
  if (resource._type === 'Book') {
    // here Book
  }
  if (resource._type === 'Post') {
    // here Post
  }
  return false;
}

let book: BookModel = { id: 1, title: "Title", publishedAt: new Date(2018, 10, 12), _type: 'Book' }

let valid = validate(book);
```

Thanks to `_type` we can apply custom logic by differentiate between structure representing specific types.

Comment: I don't think it is a good solution. First of all, it is hard to avoid collisions, how will you guarantee, that all `_type` properties are unique? TS has no control over it, now it is your responsibility to keep track of that. And it looks messy, you are populating metadata with a trash, literally. Better use abstract classes than that...

Comment: TS is not OOP only language, introduction of classes and abstract classes is bigger overhead then as you said this additional "trash". What I propose here is nothing strange, it is discriminated union - https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions. Its common practice.

Answer (score 0):

I've been through this before, the way I solved it was by using an Abstract Class instead of type/interface.

Comment: All my models are interfaces. Isn't this Angular's recommendation? So I was trying to avoid changing everything to classes.

Answer (score 0):

> The right side of the instanceof needs to be a constructor function, and TypeScript will narrow down to:
>
> 1. the type of the function’s prototype property if its type is not any
> 2. the union of types returned by that type’s construct signatures
>
> in that order

since interface is not kind of constructor, you got the type-check error.you may solve the problem by `class implements interface`.