# How to define a generic Type Guard in Typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to define an interface for my classes that contains a `isValidConfig` function to be used as type guard. But I am not sure how to declare it.

I have done this:

```
type AnyConfig = ConfigA | ConfigB | ConfigC;

public abstract isValidConfig<T extends AnyConfig>(config: AnyConfig): config is T;
```

and

```
  public abstract isValidConfig<T = AnyConfig>(config: T): config is T;
```

But I always get errors in the implementation like:

```
public isValidConfig<T extends ConfigA >(config: T): config is T {
    return config.type === TrainingTypes.A;
} /// Types of parameters 'config' and 'config' are incompatible.
      Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'ConfigA '.
```

Is it possible to do this? I haven't found the way.

Comment: I posted a related question here. It shows potentially a better way but I'm not sure if it is. It is also a more specific scenario than this thread, hence stating a new question.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78073467/typescript-return-type-dependent-on-parameter-type

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you can't have have a guard that enforce against a generic. Following from the official TS docs: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards

You can do something like this to guard against an individual type:

```js
enum ConfigTypes {
  a = 'a',
  b = 'b',
  c = 'c'
}

interface ConfigA {
  field: number;
  type: ConfigTypes.a;
}

interface ConfigB {
  otherField: string;
  type: ConfigTypes.b;
}

interface ConfigC {
  yetAnotherField: string[];
  type: ConfigTypes.c;
}

type AnyConfig = ConfigA | ConfigB | ConfigC;

export function isValidConfigA(config: AnyConfig): config is ConfigA {
  return config.type === ConfigTypes.a;
}
```

---

It's worth adding that types must be enforced at compile time because TypeScript simply cannot perform run-time checks (by then it's already been transpiled to JavaScript, which performs dynamic (run-time) checking). In other words, you can only guard against a specific known type.

If you want to check that a given expected config IS a config, then continuing from the example above, you can do:

```js
export function isValidConfig(config: AnyConfig): config is AnyConfig {
  return (
    config.type === ConfigTypes.a ||
    config.type === ConfigTypes.b ||
    config.type === ConfigTypes.c
  );
}
```

Comment: But how I define the function signature in my `Class` interface or class abstract parent? The implementation already works as you described in your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you use multiple generics I think this will work okay.

```js
interface A {
  a: number
}
interface B {
  b: string
}

function isTypeA<TA extends A, TB extends B>(val: TA | TB): val is TA {
  return typeof (val as any).a === 'number'
}

const a: A = {a: 1}
if (isTypeA(a)) {
    console.log(a.a) // okay
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77358090/8757071) in another thread — the original topic is wider but I've found what you might have been looking for among the long replies list. Also a guy [here](https://dev.to/ussdlover/generic-interface-check-function-in-typescript-3fm8) describes the same approach in more detail.

Basic idea is to use some unique property of an object you're checking — so you'll have to pass it to your checking function as a second parameter. Sounds "crutchy", but I haven't found anything better yet. What can a mere developer do when their language doesn't provide a proper way, right?

I would add 2 notes though to the aforementioned solutions:

- naming your method `instanceOf()` feels a bit off to me, I'd call it at least `instanceOfInterface()` or something like that,
- you might need to provide a correct extension to your generic type like that: `instanceOfInterface<T extends object>`.

So eventually you'll have:

```
public instanceOfInterface<T extends object>(
  entity: T,
  uniqueProperty: string,
): entity is T {
  return uniqueProperty in entity;
}
```