# Typescript: property does not exist on combined type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

The following abstracted TS scenario:

```js
interface EmotionsOkay {
  emotion: string;
  okay: "yap";
}
interface EmotionsNotOkay {
  emotion: string;
}
type UndetereminedEmotion = EmotionsOkay | EmotionsNotOkay;
const areYouOkay = (test: UndetereminedEmotion) => {
  console.log(test.okay ? "happy :D" : "sad D:");
};
```

throws a TypeScript error when console logging `test.okay`, because it apparently does not exist.

```
Property `okay` does not exist on type `UndetereminedEmotion`.
```

Even though it could very well exist, if the test passed to the method was of type `EmotionsOkay`.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this point, TS does not know what type it is, it could be `EmotionsOkay` and everything will be fine, or it could be `EmotionsNotOkay` and the property `okay` would not exists. That's why you are getting this error. You need to validate which type it is.

You can use the `in` keyword to validate that,

```
interface EmotionsOkay {
  emotion: string;
  okay: "yap";
}
interface EmotionsNotOkay {
  emotion: string;
}
type UndetereminedEmotion = EmotionsOkay | EmotionsNotOkay;
const areYouOkay = (test: UndetereminedEmotion) => {
  console.log('okay' in test && test.okay ? "happy :D" : "sad D:");
};
```

You can't be Happy if you don't have the property `okay` in the first place.

If you were wondering why you can't use `instanceof` in this case, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14426274/5784924)

[Here is a playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=11&ssc=3&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIFsD2ZiZAZwHkBrOAT2QG8AoZZCLHPALmXzClAHMBuW5TKTKsARGTgAHEXwC+1UJFiIUGbLgIA5bCXJV+DNSzYdus6mDISUAVRAATCIoagId1UxDIAvGkbqiQsgAPr6GmtpCfAh47MhwUBAAmpgArjoUPgAUkOystg5O6C5ufngAlN4AfHp00QSYADYQAHQNmFyZAOSC5J3IoMg5YMgAZCODEOzNPRQA-MgiABaSEhTMACIiyKL4cHbI68wiZbI8QA)

Comment: Hmm, I kinda understand it now and was able to fix my use-case w/ this. But why does a conditional check / if statement around that not fix the problem? Why is it necessary to use a TS syntax instead of a usual JS if statement around it?

Comment: I'm not sure i understand where you placed your `if` but if it's in the `areYouOkay` callback,it should be fine, as long as you validate that your `test` variable implements `EmotionsOkay` before checking it's `okay` property, you should be fine.

Comment: [see here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIFsD2ZiZAZwHkBrOAT2QG8AoZZCLHPALmXzClAHMBuW5TKTKsARGTgAHEXwC+1UJFiIUGbLgIA5bCXJV+DNSzYdus6mDISUAVRAATCIoagId1UxDIAvGkbqiQsgAPr6GmtpCfAh47MhwUBAAmpgArjoUPgAUkOystg5O6C5ufngAlN4AfHp0wDDImQDkguSNyKDIOWAVNHR0APT9nZYQ+AicEmDIxCCYAO4EnQAWcFMtFMD47Z5gSyhd-HTRBJgANhAAdKeYXNmjYBfryAD8yCIrEhIUzAAiIsiifBwOzIH7MERlPh0OQDIZ7BIAGnaUyKXCWUwARigIMBdtBQh4ArpMFACf4tGB0vxBmxMMg5iguI44p5oFASRd+Md8GdLtdbl1HkIytQZDwgA)

Comment: Sorry bad explanation, but I meant when you wrap it w/ an `if (test.okay)` or when using optional chaining. Shouldn't typescript know just as much as when using the `in` syntax?

Comment: That's a good question, i don't think i have an answer for that. Sorry. @josias

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Typescript type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) (like casting in other languages).

```js
interface EmotionsOkay {
  emotion: string;
  okay: "yap";
}
interface EmotionsNotOkay {
  emotion: string;
}
type UndetereminedEmotion = EmotionsOkay | EmotionsNotOkay;
const areYouOkay = (test: UndetereminedEmotion) => {
  console.log((test as EmotionsOkay).okay ? "happy :D" : "sad D:");
  // or
  console.log((<EmotionsOkay>test).okay ? "happy :D" : "sad D:");
};
```