# How to check the interface type of an object?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to evaluate an object based on two types, without looking explicitly at its children, as a value could not exist (based on my use-case).

Let's say I have two interfaces with different properties.

`interface A` & `interface B`

How would I check an object is Type of A or Type of B?

I've tried the following:

```
interface A {
  foo: "value";
}

interface B {
  bar: "value";
}

const object = {
  bar: "value"
};

function isA(object: any): object is A {
  if (object as A) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

console.log(isA(object));
```

However, the result is always returned as `True`.

**Codesandbox**
https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-gagarin-01c7y?file=/src/index.ts:0-243

Comment: Probably a duplicate: Does this answer your question? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14425568/interface-type-check-with-typescript

Comment: @AlgefAlmocera I did check this originally but it's checking to see if a key is present on the type not actually what the type of the object.

Comment: @XavierAkram a type does not exist in javascript, to which typescript compiles to, so the only way to check if an object is of a certain type is to check if it has a certain property which only belongs to that one interface

Comment: Exactly as @PoulKruijt have said.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I wasn't aware of the intimate mechanics of typescript. +1