# How to detect that the react element is a react portal?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-dom

`ReactProtal` interface like this:

```
interface ReactPortal extends ReactElement {
    key: Key | null;
    children: ReactNode;
}
```

How can I check if a react element is a react portal?

```
const element: ReactPortal | JSX.Element = getComponent();
if(isReactPortal(element)) {
   // do something with react portal
} else {
   // do something with usual react element
}
```

Current solution: check if `key` property exists

```
if('key' in element) {
  // is react portal
} else {
  // is usual react element
}
```

But I am not sure this is strong and safe.

Comment: Did you try with `instanceof` ? It might work as intended, I guess.

Comment: This might help, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14425568/interface-type-check-with-typescript

Comment: @kishore `ReactPortal` is an interface, not a value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [react-is](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-is) library to determine if the component is a portal or not. It has many utilities including [isPortal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-is#portal) function.

If you are more adventurous and want to implement something yourself. You can go through the code [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react-is/src/ReactIs.js#L134).

Comment: Nice work man!! I saw the implementation of the `isPortal` function, don't understand why compare with [ReactSymbols](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/90bde6505e/packages/shared/ReactSymbols.js#L20). But this is another question.

Comment: I got it. Each react element will has `type: Symbol(react.portal)`  or `type: Symbol(react.element)` property. Then we can compare with the value of this property.