# AWS JavaScript SDK v3 with TypeScript 4.4.2 and @types/node 16.7.10 thrown error type

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services

I updated today (after a couple of months) my `package.json` file with the latest package versions, I think the ones impacting this error are the ones in the subject of the question.

Some error handling blocks as the following one

```js
try {
  // ...
} catch(err) {
  console.log(err.message);
}
```

stopped working due to TypeScript error `2571: Object is of type 'unknown'.`

Nice! I just had to apply following simple change:

```js
try {
  // ...
} catch(err) {
  console.log(err instanceof Error ? err.message : JSON.stringify(err));
}
```

not only my code started to work once again, but I feel my code is more resilient as well.

The problem comes when I try to handle an error thrown from the AWS SDK v3.

```js
import { CloudWatchLogs, ResourceNotFoundException } from "@aws-sdk/client-cloudwatch-logs";

const cwl = new CloudWatchLogs({ region: "us-east-2" });

try {
  const logGroupName = "...";
  const logStreamName = "...";
  const { events } = await cwl.getLogEvents({ logGroupName, logStreamName });

  // ...
} catch(err) {
  if(! (err instanceof ResourceNotFoundException)) console.log(err);
}
```

In the simplified (I'm not handling pagination) above code sample I simply want to ignore the `ResourceNotFoundException`, but the `err instanceof ResourceNotFoundException` check doesn't compile since `ResourceNotFoundException` is an `interface` rather than a `class`.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14425568/interface-type-check-with-typescript/14426274#14426274) which seems could help me.

**The question is:** should I write an `instanceOf\w+Exception` function (sorry for the regexp) for each AWS exception I need to handle, or is there a common and reusable way provided by AWS?

The main reason why I'm seeking for this is not that I'm lazy (and I am), but if I write my own `instanceOf\w+Exception` functions inspecting the AWS SDK source code, my functions may stop working if Amazon will change something in the SDK.

Answer (score 3):

I found [this issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/issues/2007): I strongly suspect, at the moment, the answer is simply: no, there isn't.

**Edit:** the same issue was solved and now we can use the `instanceof` operator (I have not yet tested it).

Answer (score 1):

Update 2022

AWS SDK v3 is now using instanceof and deprecating the typescript sdkerror

[https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/service-error-handling-modular-aws-sdk-js](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/service-error-handling-modular-aws-sdk-js/)

```
import {
  InvalidSignatureException,
  ResourceNotFoundException,
  FooServiceException,
} from "@aws-sdk/client-foo";
```

Obviously replace foo by the client you are using

```
try {
  await client.send(someCommand);
} catch (e) {
  if (e instanceof InvalidSignatureException) {
    // Handle InvalidSignatureException
  } else if (e instanceof ResourceNotFoundException) {
    // Handle ResourceNotFoundException
  } else if (e instanceof FooServiceException) {
    // Handle all other server-side exceptions from Foo service
  } else {
    // Other errors
  }
}
```