# Different multiple union type in ts

Tags: typescript, union

I have 2 types like

```
interface RowOne {
    id: number;
    value: number;
    median: number;
    timestamp: string;
}

interface RowTwo {
    supply: number;
    pool1: string;
    pool2: string;
    fee: number;
}
```

Now I declare one Union Type like

```
interface Total {
   rows: RowOne[] | RowTwo[];
}
```

As usual, we should have one share field to check that the return type is `RowOne` or `RowTwo`

But now I have one function like `const data = getTotal(): Total`, this function will return data follow `RowOne` or `RowTwo`

But when I get data like `data.rows[0].supply`
it says that

```
Property 'supply' does not exist on type 'RowOne | RowTwo'.
```

So for this case, How can I pass this error?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your case, a union type does not work because it only can recognize common attributes between 2 types. You can check the document [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#unions-with-common-fields)

I'd suggest you use a generic type to determine the type's attributes

```
interface RowOne {
    id: number;
    value: number;
    median: number;
    timestamp: string;
}

interface RowTwo {
    supply: number;
    pool1: string;
    pool2: string;
    fee: number;
}

type Total<T> =  {
   rows: T[];
}

//define data with a specific generic type
const data: Total<RowOne> = {
  rows: [{ id: 1, value: 1, median: 1, timestamp: "1" }]
}

//assign generic types with an union
const getData = (): Total<RowOne | RowTwo> => {
   return data
}

const updatedData = getData()

console.log(updatedData)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=29&ssc=25&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoHsDuB5EKDeAUMicsACYBcyIArgLYBG0A3MaQG5wA2tE1dJq3Yl6EcsDggBDZlDalkYYGIDOYOPQAO1dVFABzNgF9ChUJFiIUGTABVM6ZEUWraWrdwCeMofJHIWujo3ACMumD6IEYBQSEATBFRMYowEPw0ssKmhGBeWih26BrcADx2AHzIALwkLiRQWKrUdgDaALomZgjoIOrI5HAaLcU8pba4EFW19Y2Yzcit%20GRUyKEANMhcvBkbyGISUtR7ymoa2tQARKGXyMbthDk9fWDIBhBgACJDcDXIABQAShGJXGWEmAB80FgHOhplV6sgoB9aFAQAMfo9ur1%20u5BpByN8NH93l8fkDsX0QhAAHTcdAGf54obiIlwQFAA)

Comment: You can defined `getTotal(): Total<RowOne | RowTwo>` to determine the type. Let me update my answer to align with your question

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused since typescript is unable to find `supply` **common** property in the type `Row1 | Row2`. This happens bacuase the `Row1` doesn't have the `supply` property.

To fix this issue, you have to add checks to determine whether the object contains the specific properties or not. Or better add a function to check the type of the object (Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14426274/5309486 ).

Both approaches are as follow:

```
const row = data.rows[0];

// Approach 1
function isRowTwo(obj: RowOne | RowTwo): obj is RowTwo {
  return 'supply' in obj && 'pool1' in obj;
}

if (isRowTwo(row)) {
  console.log(row.supply);
}

// Approach 2
if (`supply` in row) {
  console.log(row.supply);
}
```

You can find the same code at: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Answer (score 0):

you can use generic types like this

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoHsDuB5EKDeAsAFDLLAAmAXMiAK4C2ARtANwlkBucANnRDXrM2HZAwgVgcEIMYso7UsjDBxAZzBwGABxoaooAOaKAviRKhIsRCgyYAKpnTIiStXW3aeAT1nCFotro6DwAjHpgBiDGgcE8AEwRUTFKMBACtHIixGbEFuDQ8EjI9uiaPMgAPPYAfK5kUFhqVPYA2gC6JLkkCOggGsiGEGCl5cgAvMgAFACUNKO8lXaO6DUTa-XIUMN0UCAuog1NNK2bZGTunj40AKyH5wA0yEEh4cgARO-3ZE8vCTSfb7IJ5pDLxe4mTpKXLdYi9fpgZAUOCaeZlRbLJxrSZDEbonizEjIzQAOkamDUrQADO0APwky5ebxAA)

```
interface RowOne {
  id: number;
  value: number;
  median: number;
  timestamp: string;
}

interface RowTwo {
  supply: number;
  pool1: string;
  pool2: string;
  fee: number;
}

interface Total <T>{
  rows:T[]
}

const getTotal = (): Total<RowTwo> => {
  return {
    rows: [{
      supply: 5
      , pool1: ""
      , pool2: ""
      , fee: 2
    }]
  }
}

const data: Total<RowTwo> = getTotal()
data.rows[0]?.supply
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for strong support from community
As I posted before

> As usual, we should have one share field to check that the return type is `RowOne` or `RowTwo`

So I support we have a solution to make our code better

```
interface RowOne {
    id: number;
    value: number;
    median: number;
    timestamp: string;
}

interface RowTwo {
    supply: number;
    pool1: string;
    pool2: string;
    fee: number;
}

interface Total <T>{
   rows: T[];
}
```

In function

```
const getTotal = async <T>(): Promise<T>
```

Call:

const data  = await getTotal();

Thanks @Nick Vu