# Function returning an object type if the object is an instance of x?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need a TypeScript function to test if an object is of a specific type. If so, the method should return this type. If not the method should return undefined. I want to use this function in the following way:

```js
const mySpecialObject = isSpecialObject(source);
if (mySpecialObject) {
  console.log(mySpecialObject.getSpecialProperty());
}
```

I tried to export a function like this one:

```js
export function isSpecialObject(element: SomeBaseObject): SpecialObject  {
    if (element instanceof SpecialObject) {
        return element;
    }
    return undefined;
}
```

But the compiler claimed that 'undefined' is not assignable of Type SpecialObject

How should a TypeScript function with this behavior look?

Comment: _"If not, the method should return undefined"_ - `: SpecialObject | undefined`? Or maybe you actually want a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates).

Comment: You could use a type narrowing function to assert the behavior

Comment: Or [Interface type check with Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14425568/215552)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a type predicate function to make this thing safer!

```
export function isSpecialObject(element: SomeBaseObject): element is SpecialObject  {
    return element instanceof SpecialObject;
}

if (isSpecialObject(element)) {
   // element is safe to use as SpecialObject
}
```

It's also possible to use a type predicate function for multiple types like this:

```js
export function isSpecialObject(element: SomeBaseObject): element is SpecialObject | SpecialObjectSub1 | SpecialObjectSub2 {
    return element instanceof SpecialObject || element instanceof SpecialObjectSub1 || element instanceof SpecialObjectSub2;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I also figured now out that I can even check for multiple types using the | operator.

Answer (score 0):

Since the two possible outcome to be returned by the function are `SpecialObject` or `undefined`, so `undefined` can be added as a possible returned type. as below

```
export function isSpecialObject(element: SomeBaseObject): SpecialObject | undefined  {
  if (element instanceof SpecialObject) {
    return element;
  }
  return undefined;
}
```

Comment: Please don't use Stack Snippets unless clicking Run code snippet does something illustrative. Also, explanations of code in answers is pretty much a requisite for upvotes.

Comment: While this code works, it best if you explain why your code solves the problem instead of just pasting code.

Comment: Especially as it appears you copied the only change made to the OP's code directly from [@jonsharpe's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72384567/function-returning-an-object-type-if-the-object-is-an-instance-of-x#comment127874831_72384567)