# How to tell Typescript that casting from a less strict interface to a more strict one is ok?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to get the code I've pasted below to execute but the Typescript compiler seems to be unconvinced that I've properly ensured one interface can be cast to another based on the check I've put. What do I need to do to make it happy with this code?

```
interface Person {
  name: string,
  address?: string
}

interface PersonWithAddress extends Person {
  address: string
}

function tryLoggingAddresses(people: Array<Person>) {
  people.forEach(person => {
    if (person.address) {
      logAddress(person)
    }
  })
}

function logAddress(personWithAddress: PersonWithAddress) {
  console.log(personWithAddress.address)
}
```

Typescript error:

```
error TS2345: Argument of type 'Person' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PersonWithAddress'.
      Types of property 'address' are incompatible.
        Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
          Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.

    63       logAddress(person)
```

I know that I can force the cast by changing the line to `logAddress(person as PersonWithAddress)` but that's effectively disabling all type checking which isn't ideal. Is there anyway to do this without that?

Comment: Would a [user-defined type guard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33733258/14956277) work? For example, `function isPersonWithAddress(object: Person): object is PersonWithAddress { return 'address' in object; }`. Call it like this: `if (isPersonWithAddress(person)) { logAddress(person); }`.

Comment: If all you need is `address` then this can be simpler: https://tsplay.dev/m3PByW

Comment: @AlexWayne Unfortunately this was a toy example and in the real code I need to validate a lot more than address. Thanks for the thought though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can utilize a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) in place of your existing conditional expression. This will help inform the compiler that the data structure meets the criteria that you intend during [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis).

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=12&ssc=1&pln=16&pc=2#code/C4TwDgpgBAChBOBnA9gOygXigbwFBSlQEMBbCALikWHgEtUBzAbnyiIBN34JFEB+StTqMWAXxa5QkWAhSoA6rWAALAIKduvTFABKEAI4BXWt3YAeOEjQA+CQDNDqAMbBaaKJCuoAEkUTquHkQoAApPOUpLOQBKSnD3WmCotEUVAM1gvAJuYEN4dCkIZDsPWTQAOg5ArQxaqAByIXoGerFcXAdnV3cAG2QGdKCeUMhkMB6KGS8AbQBdaJxWO2R4UKc0alKvKGLSsYmFrIIoWhKwsp8-Qd5zr2iFvoGNINuYlgJRXE+Oxxc3dEe12CrxSSjUz14kQuqXB1UQh1Y61QKAm5UeIIUYKBlQh8LaQA)

```ts
function personHasAddress (person: Person): person is PersonWithAddress {
  return typeof person.address === 'string';
}

function logAddresses (people: Person[]) {
  for (const person of people) {
    if (personHasAddress(person)) logAddress(person);
  }
}
```

Comment: Amazing! I never knew about type guards before this. Thank you!