# Does typescript allow interface and string union types?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to implement a method like that takes a key argument that is either a `string` or an instance of the indexable type interface `IValidationContextIndex`.  The implementation looks like this:

```
  /**
   * Gets all ValidationContext container values.
   * @returns An array of ValidationContext instances contained in the cache.
   */
  public static getValidationContextValues(key: IValidationContextIndex | string ): Array<ValidationContext> {
    if (key instanceof IValidationContextIndex ) [
      return Object.values(<any> key);
    ]
    else {
      const vci = ValidationContainer.cache[<string>key];
      return Object.values(<any> vci);
    }
  }
```

Typescript give the following error for the `if` block:

> [ts] 'IValidationContextIndex' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

For most interface I think it's possible to add a `type` property (    `type: 'IValidationContextsIndex'`;
), but that does not work in this case since the the interface is an indexable type interface ....

Comment: You can use any as type

Comment: If I do `key: any` and perform an instanceof check I still get the same error ...

Comment: Remember that interfaces and types just disappear once you transpile into javascript. Those are for your code-checking and linting. Not for your end-result.

Comment: Yup I understand that part - basically the interface is gone, so Typescript is like "Dude I got nottin ..."

Comment: Maybe this will help then: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40718205/1497533

Comment: Just check your first if statement it should be curly braces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isnt a way to check the type in typescript at run time as almost everything becomes an object once transpiled, so you may have to something along what is defined as [user-defined typed guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards)

Answer (score 2):

I think this will do it (Per the tip from @indrakumara):

```
    /**
     * Gets all ValidationContext container values fpr a 
     * Object_property string valued key or a key that is an instance of 
     * IValidationContextIndex).
     * @returns An array of ValidationContext instances contained in the cache that corresponds to a specific Object_property key.
     */
    public static getValidationContextValues(key: any ): Array<ValidationContext> {
      if (typeof key === `string` ) {
        const vci = ValidationContainer.cache[<string>key];
        return Object.values(<any> vci);
      }
      else {
        return Object.values(<IValidationContextIndex> key);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces in typescript doesn't transpile into any code in javascript. So in your code, "instanceof IValidationContextIndex", IValidationContextIndex doesn't exist in javascript.

Change your interface to class or have a class implementing the interface and then check if passed parameter is instanceof that class.

Comment: It was a little easier to just check whether the instance is a string, and if not assume that is an instance of the interface ... So I cheated a little, but it's lightweight and works ...I think your way would be robust when the union type is composed of multiple interfaces ...