# how to check type of variable in typescript +angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

could you please tell me  how to check typeof of variable in typescript + angular ?

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

interface Abc {
  name : string
}
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular 6';
  a:Abc= {
  name:"sss"
  }

  constructor(){
    console.log(typeof this.a)
   // console.log(this.a instanceof Abc) 
  }
}
```

It should give `true` and `false`

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jfargi?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does 'instanceof' in TypeScript give me the error "'Foo' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here."?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46703364/why-does-instanceof-in-typescript-give-me-the-error-foo-only-refers-to-a-ty)

Comment: for `true` / `false` you have to check it against some value

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Interfaces are erased at runtime so there will be no trace of the interface in any runtime call. You can either use a class instead of an interface (classes exist at runtime and obey `instanceof`

```
class Abc {
    private noLiterals: undefined;
    constructor(public name: string) { }
}
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    name = 'Angular 6';
    a: Abc = new Abc( "sss")

    constructor() {
        console.log(this.a instanceof Abc) // Will be true 
    }
}
```

Or you can do structural checking to see if the properties of `Abc` are present at runtime in the object:

```
export class AppComponent {
    name = 'Angular 6';
    a: Abc = { name: "sss" }

    constructor() {
        console.log('name' in this.a) // Will be true 
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of testing `'name' in this.a`, given `this.a` follows an interface, one could: `const myInterface = this.a as MyInterface; console.log(myInterface.name)`

Comment: structural check works, however instanceof for class-es is a bit tricky. They only work if you initialize the variable with the new keyword. If initialized as an object, it won't fly. 
See:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vz9oyw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: I create a class which implements the interface.  Then I initialize properties in the constructor of that class.  This way I can new up an object at runtime and pass it around as the interface type, if need be.

Answer (score 33):

just use `typeof(variable);`
so in your case:

```
console.log(typeof(this.a));
```

Answer (score 9):

Try 'instanceof' or 'is':

```
a instanceof Abc;
```

See also:
[Class type check with typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12789231/class-type-check-with-typescript)

Answer (score 6):

For basic types (string, number, etc) you can check like this:

`if( typeof(your_variable) === 'string' ) { ... }`

Answer (score 3):

> **Interfaces** **only exist at compile-time and are removed after compilation,** so that code makes no sense at run-time. If you try so it will always return `false`.

Have a look here -

```
constructor(){
    console.log(typeof(this.a), '---');
    console.log(this.instanceOfA(this.a)); 
  }

  instanceOfA(object: any): object is ABc {
    return 'member' in object;
  }
```

## [Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ax4b7t?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

For more in details refer here -

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/46703380/5043867

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
  console.log(typeof (this.specialProviderSelected));
```

we can check type of variable like as string, number, object etc

```
  if((typeof (this.specialProviderSelected)) === 'string') {
     action here...
    }
   if((typeof (this.specialProviderSelected))  === 'number') {
     action here...
    }
    if((typeof (this.specialProviderSelected))  === 'object') {
     action here...
    }
```

Comment: Code only answers can almost always be improved by the addition of some explanation of how and why they work.

Comment: next time , i will try to give answers with explanations. thank u

Comment: For now, you can just [edit] your post to add some explanation.