# How to tell apart Type from Function?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an argument of type

```
((element: any) => Type<any>) | Type<any>
```

and if it is a Function i need to call it, other wise just use the Type as-is

```
getType(element: any, type: ((element: any) => Type<any>) | Type<any>): Type<any> {
    return isFunctionNotType(type) ? type(element) : type;
}
```

Unfortunately I am not sure how to write the `isFunctionNotType` method. There is an `isType` method in `@angular/core/src/type` but whenever I try using that I get the following error during compilation

```
ERROR in C:/Users/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/dist/xxxxxx/fesm5/angular-utils.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core/src/type' in 'C:\Users\xxxxxx\xxxxxx\xxxxxx\dist\xxxxxx\fesm5'
```

Is there some way to get this working without having to break up the `type` variable into two?

EDIT: I should point out since people seem to be missing the point here. In angular `Type` extends `Function`, and at run-time you will not be able to tell them apart just by doing an `instanceof` or something like that.

Comment: I don't think Angular should be the resource for type-checking, especially since you're already using Typescript. Either use the `instanceof` operator, or do some kind of duck-typing using a function that returns `Type is SpecificType`, which will satisfy the compiler. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12789231/class-type-check) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

(typeof callback === "function")

I would check if its a function, then do something for the other type with an 'else'.

Answer (score 0):

```js
type TypeFn<T> = (element: T) => Type<T>;

function isFunctionNotType<T>(type: TypeFn<T> | Type<T>): type is TypeFn<T> {
    return typeof type === 'function';
}

function getType<T>(element: T, type: TypeFn<T> | Type<T>): Type<T> {
    return isFunctionNotType(type) ? type(element) : type;
}
```

`isFunctionNotType` return type `type is TypeFn<T>` give a boolean AND will infer the return type.

Note that I added generics, it may be inappropriate so remove them in this case.

Comment: Unfortunately `typeof SomeType` returns `"function"` since `Type extends Function` (I am talking about the `Type` interface from `@angular/core`)

Comment: I see, so there is no clean way to do the check. A solution may be to wrap `TypeFn` in an object, or anything that could disting its.