# How to verify Interface with Axios GET response using TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, axios

Data is coming back successfully from the API. This is my first time calling an API using TypeScript. The problem I am having is that I am not sure if my interface successfully verifies the API data or not.

```
const App = () => {
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState<User[]>([])
  console.log('User data: ', userData);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get<User[]>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .then((response) => {
        setUserData(response.data)
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error.message))
  }, [])

  return ...
};

export default App;
```

Here is my interface

```
export interface User {
  id: number,
  name: string,
  username: string,
  email: string,
  address: Address,
  phone: string,
  website: string,
  company: Company,
}

export interface Address {
  street: string,
  suite: string,
  city: string,
  zipcode: string,
  geo: Geolocation,
}

export interface Geolocation {
  lat: string,
  lng: string,
}

export interface Company {
  name: string,
  catchPhrase: string,
  bs: string,
}
```

Comment: See [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12789231/class-type-check-in-typescript#:~:text=TypeScript%20have%20a%20way%20of,type%20you%20think%20it%20is.) for typechecking during run time.

Answer (score 1):

If you not sure about your props in interface has data or not. You could use this syntax
interface your_interface_name {
your_props_name?: type_data
}

ex: `export interface Geolocation { lat?: string, lng?: string, }`