# How to tell if an object belongs to a type

Tags: typescript

I have a simple type:

```
type person = 'man' | 'woman'
```

and I have an input string `x`.

How may I check whether it is a `person` or not?

Comment: At runtime? The types have been erased.

Comment: `const persons = ['man', 'woman'] as const; type Person = (typeof persons)[number]; const isPerson = persons.includes(x);`.

Comment: As @jonrsharpe mentioned, types are erased at runtime but as @clashsoft mentioned, if the string is 'man' or 'woman', then it is a `person`, non-binary definitions non-withstanding.

Comment: At runtime your Typescript wouldn't exist - it would have been compiled to Javascript, so you would need to perform some logic on the object you are checking the type of, with something like the typeof operator.

Comment: What of the `instanceof` operator e.g. `person instanceof Man;` where Man is the class. It should return a boolean for you to work with. Take a look at this answer for more detail on the operator https://stackoverflow.com/a/12789324/8252265

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since TypeScript types are merely a compile-time construct, there is no *built in* way to check that `x` is a `person`. However, you can write your own type narrowing function that does the equivalent:

```js
function isPerson(x: string): x is person {
  return x == 'man' || x == 'woman'
}
```

When using this function, TypeScript will automatically narrow down the type for you, e.g.:

```js
function funcThatTakesAPerson(p: person) {
  //...
}

function funcThatTakesAString(x: string) {
   funcThatTakesAPerson(x); // compile error; x is a string, not a person

   if (isPerson(x)) {
     funcThatTakesAPerson(x); // works; TypeScript knows that x is a person
   }
}
```